# AngularJs: Format Flot chart Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, format

I am using [Flot chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-flot) with AngularJs to display sale month wise, need to format series in Y Axis.

Y axis displaying pointers of the amount as 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000 etc.

Now I need to format these amount as 5K, 10K, 15K, 20K etc etc.

Can anybody suggest how can I format them?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) can help you here. I stole one from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thewarpaint/889690aeb21a8dfd7aba#file-filter-js).

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zAHjMYosnCEjFgQ8yQVA?p=preview

#### Steps

You can add your filter in a new module. As an example, call it `Utils`.

```
//filter dependency
angular.module('Utils', [])
  .filter('thousandSuffix', function () {
    return function (input, decimals) {

      var exp, rounded, suffixes = ['K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E'];

      if(window.isNaN(input)) {
        return null;
      }

      if(input < 1000) {
        return input;
      }

      exp = Math.floor(Math.log(input) / Math.log(1000));

      return (input / Math.pow(1000, exp)).toFixed(decimals) + suffixes[exp - 1];
    };
  });
```

Now you can reference `Utils` in your app.

```
//Your App
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['Utils']);
```

This should give you the ability to use the `thousandSuffix` filter in your HTML.

```
//Your Controller
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.yNums = [5000, 10000, 15000, 20000];
});

//Your HTML
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <p>The y axis numbers are:</p>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="num in yNums">{{num | thousandSuffix}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```